# Не отображаются параметры caption, title, description в InlineQueryResultPhoto Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Код следующий.

```
@dp.inline_handler()
async def inline_echo(inline_query: InlineQuery):
    text = inline_query.query or 'Введи что-то'
    result_id: str = hashlib.md5(text.encode()).hexdigest()
    item = InlineQueryResultPhoto(
        id=result_id,
        photo_url="https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/_static/logo.png",
        thumb_url="https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/_static/logo.png",
        photo_width=32,
        photo_height=32,
        # поля ниже игнорируются/не отображаются
        title="Title",
        description="Desc",
        caption="Caption",
        # это то что отправиться при нажатии
        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent("d")
    )

    await inline_query.answer(results=[item], cache_time=1)
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скриншоте, ничего кроме картинки не появляется. В чем проблема? Поля ведь заполнены, должен же быть какой-то текст, особенно caption.
Пробовал их по отдельности заполнять, тоже результата нет.
Также менял ссылку на файл айди, без результата.
UPD. Знаю, что в InlineQueryResultArticle есть поле thumb_url, и там всё работает. Есть как изображение так и title с description
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но тогда почему не работает InlineQueryResultPhoto?

Answer (score 0):

В Telegram `InlineQueryResultPhoto` используется только для вывода картинок, например чтоб выводить альбомы. Это не ошибка в коде или библиотеке, это особенность самого Telegram.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultphoto

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Но в документации написано, что есть необязательный `caption` который по факту не работает